# AccessViolationException while reading file header when project not marked as 'Prefer 32 bit'

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

The following code is used to read the first byte from a file header.

Running on Windows 8 64bit, this code works when running it under a project which marked as 'AnyCPU - Prefer 32 bit'. (.NET 4.5.1)

If its running under 'AnyCPU' (with 'Prefer 32 bit' unchecked) - it throws

> "AccessViolationException: Additional information: Attempted to read
>   or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other
>   memory is corrupt."

In previous versions of .NET it worked as 'AnyCPU'.

Why does it behave differently between 'Prefer 32 bit' checked or not?

Why does it behave differently between .net versions?

```
public class FileParser
{
    private static uint _hLib;

    public static void Parse(string fileName)
    {
        _hLib = LoadLibraryEx(fileName, 0, DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES | LOAD_IGNORE_CODE_AUTHZ_LEVEL);

        if (_hLib == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("********* Failed to load {0}.\r\nSpecified file was either not found, or is not a valid PE file.********", fileName);
            return;
        }

        ScanHeaders();
    }

    private static unsafe void ScanHeaders()
    {
        byte* pDosHeader = (byte*) _hLib;
        Console.WriteLine("pDosHeader[0] = {0}", pDosHeader[0]); // <<---- this is where it throws 'AccessViolationException' 
    }

    // From winbase.h in the Win32 platform SDK.
    //
    const uint DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES = 0x00000001;
    const uint LOAD_IGNORE_CODE_AUTHZ_LEVEL = 0x00000010;

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll"), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    static extern uint LoadLibraryEx(string fileName, uint notUsedMustBeZero, uint flags);
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to load a 32-bit dll into a 64-bit process.

Comment: If the dlls you want to load at run-time are 32-bit, change your project to x86.

Comment: @Peter If that was the problem, `ScanHeaders` would never run

Comment: Note that `DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES` is deprecated; instead, you should use `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE_EXCLUSIVE` or `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE` or both.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @HarryJohnston any suggestions on why the same code works on win7 64bit and not on win8 64bit?

Comment: @avivr: presumably on the Win7 system the module got loaded in the first 4GB of address space.  There doesn't need to be any particular reason, it may have been pure chance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be other problems, but the big one is here:

```
private static uint _hLib;
```

An `HMODULE` is pointer sized. That much should be clear by your cast to `byte*`. But `uint` is 32 bits wide, come what may. You need to declare `_hLib` to be pointer sized. For instance:

```
private static IntPtr _hLib;
```

or perhaps

```
private static UIntPtr _hLib;
```

This could explain why the code fails when it runs inside a 64 bit process.

That said, if you want to scan the headers of the DLL, it is not necessary to use `LoadLibraryEx`. Simple open the file and read its contents.